# How can i extract src attribut of embed tag

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I extract `src` attribute of embed tag with regex?

In this example(youtube video):

```
<div dir="" class="ms-rtestate-field">
    <div class="ExternalClass082784C969B644B096E1F293CB4A43C5">
        <p>
            <object width="480" height="385">
                <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ora35AzLxt0?fs=1&amp;amp;hl=fr_FR"></param>
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
                <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ora35AzLxt0?fs=1&amp;amp;hl=fr_FR" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
            </object>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm only able to extract the complete tag with this regex:

```
<embed>*(.*?)</embed>
```

result:

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ora35AzLxt0?fs=1&amp;amp;hl=fr_FR" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
```

Is it possible to get only the value of `src` attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please do not use regexp where it is unnecessary...

```
var htmlcode = '<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ora35AzLxt0?fs=1&amp;hl=fr_FR"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ora35AzLxt0?fs=1&amp;hl=fr_FR" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>';

div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlcode ;
var yourSrc = div.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0].src;
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the DOM methods already mentioned, you can also use jQuery to do this for you if it's been included (wasn't mentioned by OP):

```
var htmlcode = '<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ora35AzLxt0?fs=1&amp;hl=fr_FR"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Ora35AzLxt0?fs=1&amp;hl=fr_FR" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>';
var yourSrc = jQuery(htmlcode).find('embed').prop('src');
```